# getWidth() and getHeight changes in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a problem I want to understand with my Android Application.

I use the MPAndroidChart library to show a BarChart. I use `barchart.setDescriptionPosition(x, y);` to change the position to the top of the chart.

Now, I define the `x-` and `y-positions` through

```
        float x = barchart.getWidth()/2f + barchart.getViewPortHandler().offsetLeft();
        float y = barchart.getViewPortHandler().offsetTop();
```

EDIT: At first call `barchart.getWidth() = 0`, so apparently, the UI is not fully set. But I call `createView()` in `onActivityCreated()`, which is called after `onCreateView()`. Why is this happening?

The strange thing is that when I start the activity, it looks like this:
[image]

but when I have swiped left, then it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that not all of "Station 1" is shown, only the end "tion 1" in view 1, compared to view 2 where "Station 2" is correctly placed in the middle.

So there is something wrong with how I define the `x-` and `y-positions`.

Here is the activity code:

```
public class ShowDetailedResult extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{
ShowDetailedResultFragment detailedFragment;
float downX= 0;
float downY = 0;
float upX = 0;
float upY = 0;
int stationsnbr = 0;
int NBROFSTATIONS = 8;
final static String KEYSTATION = "STATIONNBR";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_detailed_result);
    detailedFragment = new ShowDetailedResultFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        stationsnbr = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEYSTATION,0);
    } else {
        stationsnbr = 0;
    }
    detailedFragment.setPositions(stationsnbr);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.show_detailed_result_container,detailedFragment).commit();
    View view =(View)findViewById(R.id.showDetailedRootView);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    View contView = (View)findViewById(R.id.show_detailed_result_container);
    contView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEYSTATION, stationsnbr);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final float MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                if (deltaX < 0 ){
                    stationsnbr--;
                    if (stationsnbr < 0){
                        stationsnbr = NBROFSTATIONS-1;
                    }
                    detailedFragment.setPositions(stationsnbr);
                    detailedFragment.createView();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    stationsnbr++;
                    if (stationsnbr >= NBROFSTATIONS){
                        stationsnbr = 0;
                    }
                    detailedFragment.setPositions(stationsnbr);
                    detailedFragment.createView();
                }
            }

    }

    return false;
}
}
```

and here is the fragment:

```
public class ShowDetailedResultFragment extends Fragment {
    BarChart barchart;
    ArrayList<Float> detailedResults;
    final int STATIONS [][] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}, {9,10, 19,20, 21,22}, {11,12,13}, {14,15,16}, {17, 18} , {23,24} };
    int STATIONNBR = 0;
    public ShowDetailedResultFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_detailed_result, container, false);
    }

    private ArrayList<BarEntry> getEntryList(){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> tmpList = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        int stations[] = STATIONS[STATIONNBR];
        for (int i = 0; i < stations.length; i++){
            BarEntry tmpEntry = new BarEntry(detailedResults.get(stations[i]), i );
            tmpList.add(tmpEntry);
        }
        return tmpList;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getXvals(int length){
        ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            tmpList.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        return tmpList;
    }
    public void createView(){
        ArrayList<BarEntry> resultList = getEntryList();
        BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(resultList,"Skeet");
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set);

        ArrayList<String> xVals = getXvals(resultList.size());
        BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
        barchart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
        barchart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        barchart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(110, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        barchart.setData(data);
        barchart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        float x = barchart.getWidth()/2f + barchart.getViewPortHandler().offsetLeft();
        float y = barchart.getViewPortHandler().offsetTop();
    //    System.out.println("x y: " + x + " " + y);
        barchart.setDescriptionPosition(x, y);
        barchart.setDescription("Station " + Integer.toString(STATIONNBR + 1));
        barchart.invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.init(getContext());
        detailedResults = Statistic.getDetailedResults("Skeet",LiveSession.ROUNDLENGTH);
        barchart = (BarChart)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.barchart);
        createView();
    }

    public void setPositions(int stationsToShow){
        STATIONNBR = stationsToShow;
    }

}
```

The function where most things happens is `createView()`, can it be that the size of the View is not set properly when the activity is first created?

The `(x,y)-coordinates` when creating the activity are `(31,15)`, swiping to Station 2 gives `(255,15)`. So `getWidth()` is not the same in both.

Comment: so you can't able to view the full graph without scroll correct. ?

Comment: Well, the description in the first view is shown half in the upper left corner, but when I swipe, "Station 2" is clearly visible in the top. I have made it more clear in the question.

Comment: does the station1 and station 2 are in the same graph followed by one by one?

Comment: When I swipe left or right, I change the stationsnbr and call createView from the activity, so all data is read again and set to the chart. So I recreate the entire graph everytime I swipe. I have         barchart.setTouchEnabled(false);

Comment: what is the x and y positions that you are getting when running them? station1 and station 2 on swipe

Comment: I have updated the question with that information.

Comment: did you try setting the x and y manually to some values like 10 or something, without using getwidth?

Comment: No, why should I? It needs to be adjusted to different screensizes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101486/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-erik).